# Error while porting a VisualAge Smalltalk 4.5 application to VA Smalltalk 8.6

Tags: oop, smalltalk, porting

I am porting an old (circa year 2000) IBM VAST 4.5 application to VA Smalltalk.

I managed to import the app from the VAST repository to my new VA Smalltalk repository with no error messages. But when I try to load the application this error occurs:

> Error: 365   Cannot complete the load because CwItem can only be
>   defined by one of ('CwControls V 4.5a' 'CwWindowsControls V 8.6.0 
>   [269]').

I understand that CwControls changed to CwWindowsControls but my Smalltalk knowledge is very rusty: I have no idea how to solve this.

Someone in the VA Smalltalk group mentioned a similar situation but his answer is a bit cryptic to me:

"CwControls app name is changed in new version as CwWindowsControls. When I create a empty app named CwControls, I can load apps uses controls in this app."

I know that I can create an empty app called CwControls but then my application will not compile as the methods normally provided by the original CwControls will not be present.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Is the error occurring when you load a Config Map or an Application?  If you're loading a config map, is CwControls listed as one of the applications you're loading?

Comment: Hi @David-Buck, I'm loading an Application that uses CwControls as a prerequisite.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like CwWindowsControls already defines CwItem. When you load CwItem from the other project it is defined by CwControls though.  I'm not familiar with VA but you might be able to resolve the issue by first deleting CwItem where it's defined by CwWindowsControls, then loading the other project and finally (possibly) refactor CwItem to be defined by CwWindowsControls.

Comment: It's a good idea, I will try it. Maybe I will define a new CwControls app inherited from CwWindowsControls.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to solve my problem.

My application needed another application called CwControls. But CwControls had changed its name to CwWindowsControls.

So, inspired by the answer by @MikeLeske, I just created an empty app called CwControls. That way VA Smalltalk let me continue the load.

Another error appeared then:

"Error: 365   Cannot complete the load because AbtCwPanel can only be defined by one of ('AbtRunWinCwControlsApp V 4.5' 'AbtWinRunViewsSubApp V 8.6.0  [269]')."

But the answer was similar: I just created an empty app called AbtRunWinCwControlsApp.

Now I have my 13 year old application loaded into my image. Time to work!!!

Thanks.

Comment: You could also have used the Application Editions editor to change the prerequisites before loading.  Since you have it loaded now, though, you may as well change the prerequisites from the Application Manager.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but with SstHttpSupport which became SstHttpCommunications and such.
I fixed this by "Managing" the application and removing the requirement for SstHttpSupport.
I then successfully ported the application into VAST 8.6.
Knowing that I no longer had SstHttpSupport, I add SstHttpCommunications as the new requirement in 8.6.
Hope this helps